# MS SQL numeric data type and convertion with removing zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
create table test_int
    (
     num bigint
    )

insert into test_int (num)
values (4096);
```

My task is to calculate 4096/1024/1024 and get decimal answer. Ok, int doesn't store values after dot, so:

```
select CAST (num as decimal)/1024/1024 AS decimal, ROUND ((CAST (num as decimal)/1024/1024),4,1) AS numeric  from test_int
```

First one is pure resault, second one is after rounding:

> ```
> decimal         numeric
> 0.00390625000 0.00390000000
> ```

The task is to remove empty zeroes after values.

```
select convert(decimal(25,5), 4096/1024/1024 ,0)
```

returns 0.00000.

So how can I get 0.0039 instead of 0.00390000000? 
Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: The "zeros" are there because of the data type of the result. a) They can usually be ignored, b) you can usually deal with them by applying appropriate formatting at your presentation layer and c) there's no systematic way to deal with them down at the SQL level without already knowing the value of the result.

Comment: I see, but, it seems to me that there should be the way smthng like checking if after number there is a zero, than cut down zero and right part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the result to `FLOAT`.

**Query**

```
SELECT
CAST
(
    CAST(num as decimal)/1024/1024 
    AS FLOAT
) AS decimal, 
CAST
(
    ROUND((CAST (num as decimal)/1024/1024),4,1) 
    AS FLOAT
) AS numeric  
from test_int;
```

**Result**

```
+---------------+---------------+
| decimal       |   numeric     |
+---------------+---------------+
| 0.00390625    | 0.0039        |
+---------------+---------------+
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/119bd/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer will be accepted in 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This one will work , but if i'm not mistaken , this will only work for 2008 version and above.

```
SELECT CONVERT(DOUBLE PRECISION, 0.00390000000)

result: 0.0039
```

Comment: Thanks a lot anyway - I have 2008 in other projects.

Comment: @Cove your welcome :) , oh i see.. i haven't tried it yet in lower version.. as i know that it will only work in 2008 above.. but i'm glad that it works :)